# DbContext disposing, dbcontext factory, unit of work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

Let's say i've a DbContextFactory which I use in repositories to get DbContext
(I'm not sure it'a the best solution).

```
public class DbContextFactory : Disposable, IDbContextFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, System.Data.Entity.DbContext> _dbContexts;

    public DbContextFactory()
    {
        _dbContexts = new Dictionary<Type, System.Data.Entity.DbContext>();
    }

    public T GetDbContext<T>() where T : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, new()
    {
        if (!_dbContexts.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _dbContexts.Add(typeof(T), new T());
        }

        return _dbContexts[typeof(T)] as T;
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        foreach (var kvpDbContext in _dbContexts)
        {
            kvpDbContext.Value?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And i have UnitOfWork which i inject in BusinessLogic class

```
public class UnitOfWork<T> : IUnitOfWork
    where T : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, new()
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;
    private T _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public T DbContext => _dbContext ?? (_dbContext = _dbContextFactory.GetDbContext<T>());

    public void Commit()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

than i call repository method, and let's say it throws an exception:

```
    public void CreateUser(User user)
    {
        _userRepository.Add(user);

        throw new Exception();

        UnitOfWork.Commit();
    }
```

what happend if i call other repository method in the same request (or just do not use factory as instance-per-request), and that method end successfully, and UnitOfWork.Commit() will be called and does it means that changes made in CreateUser method which failed will be saved too ? or just after throwing exception the connection close and there's no risk the changes from that method will be saved?

**To make it more clear:
I want to host that in WCF service, let's say in singleton mode.
And then - one request call method which contains multiple (for example 5) repository calls, and  first three will success and the fourth will fail, it means i won't call UnitOfWork.Commit() there. 
And then other request come, and it's just success. Does it mean, changes from first three repositories calls from previous method will be saved?
Because of singleton - there'll be still the same DbContextFactory sa the same DbContext.**

Comment: It depends on what happens with that Exception.... If you do not handle it then the user would get a 500 error (I assume this is asp.net as you mention requests). If you do handle it and the request continues the next call to savechanges on the same dbcontext instance would generate the same exception.

Comment: i edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: @JeloneK `DbContext` is an implementation of *Unit Of Work* pattern already. There's no much sense to wrap it again into another Unit of Work like you did. That additional wrapper serves no purpose.

Comment: *let's say in singleton mode* Why? Let's say instance per request mode and the whole question has become irrelevant.

Comment: You do not want a DbContext instance sticking around for multiple requests. You want a new instance for each request at minimum. That said I would not create an abstraction/wrapper for your Entity Framework. Why? The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Answer (score -1):

As @Igor said in the comments, whether you handled or not that exception makes a difference, but as your scenario involves calling anothet repository on the same request, I'll assume you did handled It.

As you said you would reuse the same instance of your DbContextFactory and that's the guy holding your DbContext instances, it's safe to say that, unless you disposed that factory somewhere else, your context would still have that same instance of User added to it and thus calling Commit on that same context on anothet repository would still insert said User.